# New version of jquery(3.3.1) partialview document.ready called after ajax success event finish... why?

Tags: jquery

I have upgraded JQuery version 3.3.1 and I have noticed, when I use ajax to refresh table on success as below

```
success: function (oResponse) {
  $("#DivID").html(oResponse);
}
```

oResponse is a partialview in string format and partialview has some jquery code and that just simple code as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var wColumnIndex = [3, 8, 9];
  debugger;
});
```

In the new version of jquery, the document.ready in partialview  is called after ajax success event finished, but in an old version of jquery, document.ready in partialview  was called when you loaded partialview in div before success finished.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: how can you call a event before the code that triggers it is appended to the page?

Comment: @madalinivascu maybe he meant `success: function (oResponse) {
  $("#DivID").html(oResponse); someOtherCode(); 
}` would run someOtherCode() after the document.ready in the partialview in one version and immediately before the partialview document.ready in another version

Comment: when this line $("#DivID").html(oResponse); execute partialview $(document).readl(function(){}); should call as it was working fine in old jquery version (2.2.4)